# Opening and reading files in Python not working

Tags: python, file

I am trying to build a program that reads a value from a separate text file. In this case, it is named "Test.lang". It contains the text "Hello World".

My program was working just fine with:

---

```
from sys import *

def open_file(filename):
print (filename)

def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])

run()
```

Then, when I tried to change it to:

```
from sys import *

def open_file(filename):
   data = open(filename, "r").read()
   print (data)

def run():
   data = open_file(argv[1])

run()
```

It does not work. I get 4 errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Senior Project\basic.py
", line 10, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Senior Project\basic.py
", line 8, in run
    data = open_file(argv[1])
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Senior Project\basic.py
", line 4, in open_file
    data = open(filename, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.lang'
```

What is really confusing me is the last one. How did the previous program work, but now test.lang doesn't exist?
Please help me.﻿

Comment: There's only 1 error. The whole message is a [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Comment: Is the filename test.lang or Test.lang?

Comment: Judging from the path, it looks like Windows, where names are not case sensitive.

Comment: Maybe wrong current working directory?

Comment: can you `import os` & `print [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]` and let us know what it prints? If the file you are trying to open does not appear when you print, that explains why the file does not exist. You can also print `os.getcwd()` and ensure your working directory is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do this.

To read a file:

```
file = open('Directory Of The File.txt', 'r')
MyVariable = file.read()
file.close()
```

To write a file:

```
file = open('Directory Of The File.txt', 'w')
file.write('Insert Text, Variable or Other Data Here!')
file.close()
```

It's as easy as that!
You can change the .txt for .lang or any other supported file extension!
Please reply and let me know if this worked for you :)